# Erro no Unity 3D código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, unity3d

Estou fazendo um Voxel World estilo Minecraft no Unity 3D, porém está dando o seguinte problema: **BCE0051: Operator '*' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'System.Type' and a right hand side of type 'float'.**

```js
#pragma strict

var TamX: int;
var TamZ: int;

var Terreno: GameObject[,];
var Bloco: GameObject;

var x: int;
var z: int;

var AlturaMaxima = int;
function Start () {
 Terreno = new GameObject[TamX, TamZ];
 for(x=0;x<TamX;x++)
  for(z=0;z<TamZ;z++)
  Terreno[x,z] = Instantiate(Bloco,
  Vector3(x*Bloco.transform.localScale.x,0,z*Bloco.transform.localScale.z),
  Quaternion.identity);
Elevacao(0);
}

function Update () {
 
}

function Elevacao (seed: float)
{
 var altura: int;
 for(x=0;x<TamX;x++)
 for(z=0;z<TamZ;z++)
  {
  altura = AlturaMaxima*Mathf.PerlinNoise((x+seed)/Mathf.Sqrt(TamX),(z+seed)/Mathf.Sqrt(TamZ));
  Terreno[x,z].transform.position.y = Mathf.Floor(altura)*Bloco.transform.localScale.y;
  }
}
```

Sei que o problema está nesta linha

```js
altura = AlturaMaxima*Mathf.PerlinNoise((x+seed)/Mathf.Sqrt(TamX),(z+seed)/Mathf.Sqrt(TamZ));
```

Nele estou tentando aplicar blocos de altura em meu terreno, gostaria de fazer esta ideia ainda, mas não sei de qual outro modo realizar, agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o que está acontecendo no seu caso é que `AlturaMaxima` é um tipo, ou seja, você está tentando fazer uma operação de multiplicação de um tipo de variável com um valor de variável de ponto flutuante, algo semelhante a seguinte operação:

```
int * 1.0; //Os valores não correspondem aos reais, porém seus tipos sim.
```

Sugiro mudar seu código de:

```
var AlturaMaxima = int;
```

Para

```
var AlturaMaxima: int;
//Ou
var AlturaMaxima = 0;
```

Com essa alteração, a variável AlturaMaxima deixará de ser um tipo e passará a ser um inteiro, o que resolverá seu erro de multiplicação com valores ilegais.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!